Solving the wave equation of a tensor $h_{\mu\nu} = (1/2) (e_\mu e_\nu + e_\nu e_\mu)$
It is known that the solution to the wave equation for a tensor
$$
\square h_{\mu\nu} = 0
$$
is
$$
h_{\mu\nu}(\vec{x}, t) = \int \frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3} \sum_{\lambda=+,\times} \left( \epsilon_{\mu\nu}^{(\lambda)}(\vec{k})  a_{\vec{k},\lambda} e^{i(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x} - \omega_k t)} + \epsilon_{\mu\nu}^{(\lambda)*}(\vec{k})  a_{\vec{k},\lambda}^* e^{-i(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x} - \omega_k t)} \right)
$$
It is also know that in geometric algebra, this equation holds:
$$
h_{\mu\nu} = (1/2) (e_\mu e_\nu + e_\nu e_\mu)
$$
I am interested in the wave equation, where I have replaced $h_{\mu\nu}$ with its geometric algebra formulation $(1/2) (e_\mu e_\nu + e_\nu e_\mu)$.
$$
\frac{1}{2} \square (e_\mu e_\nu + e_\nu e_\mu) = 0
$$
Specifically, I am looking for an expression of $e_\mu$ and of $e_\nu$ in terms of a sum over modes (instead of with the usual $h_{\mu\nu}$), that satisfies the wave equation above.

Have you tried removing the geometric algebra by expanding the definition of multiplication of vectors?

Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/817912/2451
